# Flush InputStreamResource of spring rest endpoint

Tags: java, spring, stream

i have an application which displays the contents of a stream. This stream is provided via Spring Rest. The content of the stream is getting pushed infrequently from another thread.

This works already, but the only thing i have problems with is "flushing" the stream. Currently i see the content only when the stream is closed, but i want to have a real time display of the content.

I tested this by calling the endpoint via chrome/firefox and the (full) contents only appear after the stream is closed (page is not loading anymore). Also in my application the content is displayed only in the end, not in the meantime.

```
@GetMapping("/session")
public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> openSession(){
    var inLog = new PipedInputStream();
    var logWritable = new PipedOutputStream(inLog);

    spawnThreadAndPushMessages(logWritable);

    return ResponseEntity.ok()
        .contentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
        .body(new InputStreamResource(inLog));
}
```

Iam writing to the PipedOutputStream (logWritable) like this:

```
spawnThreadAndPushMessages(OutputStream logWritable){
    //thread stuff etc omitted for clarity
    logWritable.write("test".getBytes());
    logWritable.flush();
}
```

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

so i finally figured it out:

```
.contentType(MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM)
```

I had to rethink my architecture. I now write into a concurrent list in my other thread. My Endpoint looks like this now:

```
@GetMapping("/session")
public ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody> openSession(){
var shutdown = new AtomicBoolean(false);
var tobeFlushed = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<String>();
//thread management etc
createThreadAndWriteToList(tobeFlushed, shutdown);

return ResponseEntity.ok()
    .contentType(MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM)
    .body(outputStream -> {
      while (!shutdown.get()) {
        tobeFlushed.forEach(x -> {
          try {
            outputStream.write((x+"\n").getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            outputStream.flush();
          } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
        });
        tobeFlushed.clear();
    }
    System.out.println("Finished request!! ------------------------");
  });
}
```